# Can a Bios update affect GRUB in any way?

Tags: bios, grub

I have dual boot (windows and ubuntu) on my ssd with Grub.
I want to update the BIOS.
However, I am scared if it can impact Grub in any way? Are the two connected at all...

Answer (score 2):

BIOS update *can* cause problems.

A fast search found the following example posts.
I remark that all the posters found solutions to their problems, although not without
search and trial.

- [Grub does not load after bios update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036980/grub-does-not-load-after-bios-update)
- [Linux boot loader is not detected after BIOS update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236978/linux-boot-loader-is-not-detected-after-bios-update)
- [BIOS Update -> no more dual Boot Grub screen -> farewell ubuntu?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2385927)

I remark that such cases are usually rare, but you should still take very good backups
before updating the BIOS.